# WPF Resource[this object key] causes a deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I'm running a WPF project under .NET Framework 4.5.1.
Sometimes, the method being run on a background thread blocks

```
lock (some_lock_up_the_callstack)
...
var rsc = App.Current.Resources["some_key"] as System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
```

At the same time the Main Thread is also waiting on `some_lock_up_the_callstack` while trying to access a DataBinding.

The requested resource with key `some_key` is actually located in a merged dictionary.

I cannot seem to be able to reproduce this issue with a small test project and [the msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms601221(v=vs.110).aspx) on it does not seem to cover any thread-safety points. I tried locking the main thread and trying to access resources while it was locked to see, if the Resources[] accessor locks the main thread, but this doesn't seem to be the case. At least i cannot reproduce it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: are you awaiting your background task anywhere in the UI Thread context?

Comment: Yes, the main thread is waiting on the lock held by the background thread.

Comment: Not what I meant, but it doesn't matter (just tested something). Anyway, locking down your UI Thread sounds like a bad approach... how about starting another task for your lock action or not read-locking on your resource access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/ResourceDictionary@cs/1586720/ResourceDictionary@cs) for the ResourceDictionary

it seems that because `CanBeAccessedAcrossThreads` is `true` for my case, the accessor for the resource locks `SyncRoot` which in case of `CanBeAccessedAcrossThreads == true` means that it actually locks `SystemResources.ThemeDictionaryLock`. So when the wpf engine is doing something it may lock that as well causing a deadlock.